# alias zsh: parse error near `do'

Tags: terminal, alias, zsh, parse-error

I'm facing an issue with an alias for `zsh`.

I've this alias in my `.zprofile` file: `` alias cleanimg="for i in `docker images | grep '<none>' | awk '{print $3}'`; do; docker rmi -f $i; done" ``.

When running `cleanimg` from my terminal I'm getting this error: `` zsh: parse error near `do' ``.

I tried to remove the `;` right after the `do` keyword but it didn't fix the issue.
However, that alias runs correctly if I execute the code directly from a terminal.

Can anybody help me with this syntax error?

Thanks by advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want is to clean your docker images, you can set an alias like this:

```
alias cleanimg='docker rmi -f $(docker images -q -f "dangling=true")'
```

The sub commande `docker images -q -f "dangling=true"` return all your id to remove and since `docker rmi` accept arguments you can pass them directly

Answer (score 6):

Don't try to use an alias for this; use a function.

```
cleanimg () {
  for i in $(docker images | awk '/<none>/ {print $3}'); do
    docker rmi -f "$i"
  done
}
```

This saves you from having to get the quoting right so that the command substitution runs when the alias is *used*, rather than when it is *defined*.

(Also, `grep | awk` pipelines can almost always be implemented using `awk` alone.)

(I also wonder if you can dispense with `awk` and the loop using the `--filters` option instead; maybe `docker rmi -f $(docker images -q -f "dangling=true")`?)

Comment: Hello and thanks for your answer!

I pasted your function in `.zshrc`, restarted my shell and I'm getting the following error: ``.zshrc:29: parse error near `done'``
The second `done` seems to trigger a syntax issue.
Any idea?

Comment: It's a typo I guess, the `done` on the `docker rmi` line is not needed (for; do; done)

Comment: Yeah, not sure how I ended up with two `done`s. Probably copied the first one and didn't notice it was there, so typed my own.

Answer (score -1):

You have an extra semicolon in your for loop, just fix it to -
`alias cleanimg="for i in`docker images | grep '' | awk '{print $3}'`; do docker rmi -f $i; done"`

Comment: While not necessary, the additional `;` also does not hurt and removing it does not solve the issue.